# python re.sub() with ?P

Tags: python, regex

Can I use a variable from the first argument of re.sub (), to use it in the second argument? Let me explain with an example:

```
re.sub(r'(?P<id>>>>[0-9]+)', 'sometext(?P=id)sometext', self.text))
```

Can I use id variable in 'sometext(?P=id)sometext'? Actually, this code dont work, so i came here.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: The second argument of `re.sub()` can be a function.  It is called for each pattern match and is passed a match object.  It should return the new string, so you can obtain the variable in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to a capturing group by number, e.g. the first capturing group would be `\1`.